# Android Studio shows unused statements

Tags: android, import

After I include a gradle project from my locale disk I have a problem with the import statements.

Before I used the `themoviedbapi` as an compile statement in my gradle.

Now I need to modify some object. I downloaded the lib, move this to my `Project` folder (outside the app folder) and I add the lib to gradle `compile  project(':themoviedbapi')`

The import worked well, but all of the import statements are shown as unused. The Objects are also marked red with `Cannot resolve symbol xxx`

If I try to compile the project, there are no errors.
If I remove the "unused" import statements I get errors while compiling.

A android studio restart doesnt fix the problem.

Do you have idea's whats happend and how to fix it?

---

**UPDATE 1**

My Project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.philipp.serieswatchlist"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/models'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    })
    //compile 'com.omertron:themoviedbapi:4.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    //compile 'info.movito:themoviedbapi:1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile project(':themoviedbapi')
}
```

The movie DB api:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'info.movito'
version = '1.5-SNAPSHOT'

description = """TMDB-API"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6



repositories {

     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version:'2.4.4'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version:'2.4.4'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version:'2.4.4'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:'3.3.2'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version:'1.10'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version:'1.7.7'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version:'18.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.11'
    compile(group: 'org.yamj', name: 'api-common', version:'1.1') {
       /* This dependency was originally in the Maven provided scope, but the project was not of type war.
       This behavior is not yet supported by Gradle, so this dependency has been converted to a compile dependency.
       Please review and delete this closure when resolved. */
    }
}
```

Settings:

```
include ':app', ':themoviedbapi'
```

Comment: And the `themoviedbapi` is in `settings.gradle`?

Comment: `settings.gradle` : include ':app', ':themoviedbapi'

Comment: I also tried to remove the .iml file and the .idea folder. But nothing happends

Comment: Is the library inside directory themoviedbapi/libs/{name}.jar and `build.gradle` in this module contains 'compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])' inside `dependencies` closure?

Comment: It looks like `PROJECT_ROOT/themoviedbapi/...` `PROJECT_ROOT/app/...` where app is my android application.
The android application has a `compile fileTree...`

Comment: Paste build.gradle of both modules. I assume, that `themoviedbapi` is a .jar file, right?

Comment: I updated the question.
And the api is a project not a jar file. Because I need to modify some objects.

Comment: Have no idea. Double check import statements, and class packages. The project compiles though....

Comment: The problem also happends by this Class `import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;`

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm having similar issues in my project

Comment: @ZayinKrige No, unfortunately not. At that time I did not get the project integrated locally.
The easiest way was to add things via the graphical gradle configuration editor in the studio